# Problems showing stiViewerControl stimulsoft

Tags: c#

In the form of stiViewerControl programs have used stimulsoft reports 2015.2
exe files produced after running the program associated files Stimulsoft.Base.dll, Stimulsoft.Controls.dll, Stimulsoft.Controls.Win.dll, Stimulsoft.Report.dll, Stimulsoft.Report.Win.dll that the program there is no problem and run programs made the report shows.
But when dll files with exe files using **ILMerge** integrated applications made after the final file and execute the message **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** shows and programs will not run.
please guide me.